# ActionView::Template::Error (Cannot visit ThreadSafe::Array): - Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an application that was running great in development, but when I deployed it, I keep getting this error when I access my cart controller:

ActionView::Template::Error (Cannot visit ThreadSafe::Array)

it says that the error is in this line:

```
(<%= @cart_items.count %> itens)
```

Does anybody know how to solve it?

EDIT: Here is the stack trace

```
I, [2016-01-05T21:45:14.679041 #4470]  INFO -- : Processing by 

CartsController#show as HTML
I, [2016-01-05T21:45:14.725732 #4470]  INFO -- :   Rendered carts/show.html.erb within layouts/application (4.7ms)
I, [2016-01-05T21:45:14.725894 #4470]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 47ms (ActiveRecord: 1.9ms)
F, [2016-01-05T21:45:14.727838 #4470] FATAL -- :
ActionView::Template::Error (Cannot visit ThreadSafe::Array):
    22:   <div class="panel-heading">
    23:     <h3 class="panel-title">
    24:       <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Meu carrinho <small><% if @cart_items.present? %>
    25:         (<%= @cart_items.count %> itens)
    26:         <% end %>
    27:       </small>
    28:     </h3>
  app/views/carts/show.html.erb:25:in `_app_views_carts_show_html_erb___1773486621924863592_30719520'
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is your production environment?

Comment: ubuntu, nginx passenger and mysql

Comment: Post the entire stacktrace. It looks like something is replacing `Array`.

Comment: Edited my post so I can add the stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem, I don't know why, but my @cart_items was not an array, so I changed @cart_items.count to @cart_items.length and it worked!

Thanks!

Comment: what version of rails and ruby are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and was not related with "count" or "length" the issue was with the ruby version that I was using (ruby 2.4 dev), be sure you are using a stable ruby and rails versions.

see [issue #23720](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/23720)